# Tooltips containing some component, like a datable or progressBar, instead of text

Tags: datatable, tooltip, wicket, popover

Is there any way to use tool tips, but instead of text, put some component in it, like a datatable, label, panel or similar?

Somthing like [this](http://wicket.visural.net/examples/tooltips), but with a component instead of text.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery UI Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content) with custom content.

You could place the markup you want to have in the tooltip in your output html, hide it in CSS and reference it in the jquery ui tooltip.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ ,but only in title text,<input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes." /></p>